# Google Analytics - Access Custom reports created in the GUI via API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to build a report in the gui and access it via API, (PHP .NET whatever).
Is there any way to do it?
The reason is that I want to let the Marketing people built their reports in the GUI, and ill access it via the API to import it to our databases.
If it was a single report so I assume its doable, but we are talking about 10+ reports that needs to be imported to our databases.
I if I am building a report and naming it VISITS_PER_COUNTRY.
so I can have this.

```
$ga = new ga();
$result = $ga->fetchReport("VISITS_PER_COUNTRY");
print_r($result);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Currently, this cannot be done through the API.

There is a feature request in for it:

[Issue 23: Expose Custom Reporting trough API](http://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=23&q=custom%20report&colspec=ID%20Component%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary)

Custom reports are queries for dimensions and metrics. They may include filters as well. They can usually be duplicated with a query to the API.